# Has anybody ever seen this "standard form" for an exponential function before?

Tags: notation, exponential-function, education

I recently worked with a student who mentioned this "standard form" of an exponential function taught to him by his teacher:
$$f(x)=a\cdot b^{c(x-h)}+k.$$
(Contrast this with the form $f(x)=a\cdot b^x+k$.) He was given a graph of an exponential function and told to determine the equation of the graph. I explained that one can reduce to the form $f(x)=a\cdot b^x+k$ via the mappings $a\cdot b^{-ch}\mapsto a$ and $b^c\mapsto b$, at which point one can easily read off the equation given two points and the horizontal asymptote. But I'm curious why the first form of the exponential equation was given to him in the first place.

1. Has anyone ever seen this so-called "standard form" before? I didn't find anything after a quick Google search.
2. If so, what are the interpretation of the variables $h$ and $k$ here?

Comment: If it's expressing exponential growth or decay over time, $h$ is the initial time or the time of a reference baseline against which the  growth is measured.  Similarly if $x$ is some other parameter controlling the growth.

Comment: This is traditionally how transformations are taught in high school, at least where I'm from. A function $y=f(x)$ becomes $y=a \cdot f[b(x-h)] + k$ after undergoing: (i) a vertical expansion/compression by factor $a$; (ii) a horizontal expansion/compression by factor $1/b$; (iii) translation(s) $h$ units right/left and $k$ units up/down. If $a$ and/or $b$ are negative, there would also be reflections across the $x$- and/or $y$-axes respectively. In your example the traditional $b$ has been replaced with a $c$ as the $b$ was already used for the base.

Comment: @A.J. Ah, that makes sense. It’s likely an attempt to express all exponential functions in terms of the “parent function” $f(x)=b^x$. I still disagree that it’s the _standard_ form, but that does explain its origin.